# running multiple processes, each with a different set of values for the environment variable

Tags: python-3.x, bash, gnu-parallel

I have a number of jobs. Typically I start the jobs manually by opening a number of terminal windows, and in each terminal window setting certain environment variables to different values and then invoking my programs manually. For example:

```
Terminal 1 commands:
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
./run_application1.sh

Terminal 2 commands:
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=10
./run_application2.sh

.
.
.

Terminal 8 commands:
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=5
./run_application8.sh
```

As you can see in each terminal I invoke some application (run_applicationX.sh) and each uses a different value for OMP_NUM_THREADS.
Now I want to write a script (bash or python, whichever is most suitable) that generalizes this. In other words I can pass a jobs number (say --jobs=2 for example) as well as an array A[] that is equal in length to --jobs, as well as a list of N applications (run_application1.sh, ...., run_applicationN.sh). Then I want to execute all the N applications, where at each instant at most --jobs applications are running in parallel. Furthermore the each application is supposed to use the value in A[#current job number] for its environment variable. In other words I am looking for something like this:

```
parfor i=1...N
   export OMP_NUM_THREADS=${A[JOB NUMBER]}
   ./run_application{i}.sh
```

where at most --jobs applications are ever run in parallel. What is the best way to do this? I know that the GNU parallel tool could be used to do this, but I am not sure how I could assign a different set of environment variables based on the current jobs number. Notice that the job number is an integer between 1 and --jobs, which guarantees that the same set of environment variable values are never used simultaneously. Thanks

Comment: i'd suggest you go with python. use a conf file (e.g. yaml/json/...) to define your job params. this way it'll be extensible.

Comment: In the pseudo code "parfor i=1...N ; export OMP_NUM_THREADS=${A[JOB NUMBER]} ;  ./run_application{i}.sh


Where does JOB_NUMBER get the value from ? From the description, there should be two loops (job loop, application loop) - not clear how do they interact
Also, can you clarify the concurrency limit - not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear to me what you want, but lets see if we together can build it.

```
app1() {
    export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$1
    sleep 1
    echo app1 $OMP_NUM_THREADS
}
app2() {
    export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$1
    sleep 1
    echo app2 $OMP_NUM_THREADS
}
app3() {
    export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$1
    sleep 1
    echo app3 $OMP_NUM_THREADS
}
app4() {
    export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$1
    sleep 1
    echo app4 $OMP_NUM_THREADS
}
export -f app1 app2 app3 app4

parallel app{1} {2} ::: 1 2 3 4 :::+ 2 3 5 7
```

Or compute OMP_NUM_THREADS based on job number using Perl code

```
seq 4 | parallel app{} '{= $_= seq()*seq()+1 =}'
```

To guarantee that not two jobs use the same value (often used for CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES), you can use the job slot number:

```
# 0..3
seq 10 | parallel -j 4 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES={= $_=slot()-1 =} app{}'
```

Or:

```
# 1..4
seq 10 | parallel -j 4 'app{} {%}'
```